# Convert properly int to uint in compute shader

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, directx, hlsl

In a compute shader, I'm using a `r16ui` image and I have a problem:

```
layout (binding = 0, r16ui) uniform writeonly uimage2D texture;
imageStore(texture, iTextureCoords, uvec4(0xffff, 0, 0, 0));
```

The result in `buffer` is not `0xffff` but `32767`. How can I convert `0xffff` `int` to `uint` properly inside shader?

Comment: That sounds rather strange. Even if we assume that the conversion would really be the problem, shader internally work with 32 bit integers. Even if you use `uint x = (int)0xFFFF;` the uint should still contain 0xFFFF. How do you check the value of the buffer? Are you sure that your image internal format is not 16-bit signed integer?

Comment: I'm checking buffer values using glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED_INTEGER, GL_INT, bufferOut);. 
Hower when i fill texture just after creation with 0xffff using glTexSubImage2D(0, 0, 0,
currentTextureSize, currentTextureSize, GL_RED_INTEGER, GL_INT, bufferIn); values are correct. Buffer contains only wrong value where value is higher than 32767 and change has been made by compute shader.

Comment: Nice that you solved it, but you also really shouldn't upload/download `GL_INT` data if you have a unsigned integer texture. There are always conversions happening which are not guaranteed to behave the same during glGetTexImage or from inside a shader.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm wokring with Java so I don't have a choice in this area :/. I can use only ints or shorts not unsigned types sadly. I'm running unit tests on diffrent video cards (Radeons and GeForces) and so far I haven't any problem with this conversion. Besides glGetTexImage I'm only using in unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

Ok problem was solved!
I'have passed texture to compute shader (by bindImage) as GL_R16I not GL_R16UI. That was the problem.